# In the phrase "common sense", in what sense of the word is "common" used?

Tags: etymology, phrases, history, meaning

As I understand it, there are [several definitions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/common) of *common*, but I can't find any source that can highlight the etymology of the phrase.

The linked definitions are pretty rigorous, but a less strict, collapsed version might boil down to two relevant definitions:

1. Common, as in shared amongst many in the group (a *common* goal)
2. Common, as in general, appearing frequently; widespread (a *common* sight)
3. "4c : just satisfying accustomed criteria : elementary "
   (The third definition is cited directly from M-W at coleopterist's suggestion)

Comment: Any particular reason why you've dismissed _sense 4_ of Webster's definition of _common_?

Comment: Hmmm @coleopterist you may be right. I felt that 4a was covered under the first definition I provided, and 4b did not apply, but 4c looks very possible. That said, I'm still interested in the etymology and usage, so I'll add 4c to the question but leave it open. Thanks.

Comment: The AHDEL defines _common sense_ as a compound noun: Sound judgment not based on specialized knowledge. So do Collins and MW. Whilst this compound is transparent (easily broken down into constituents) (provided the correct sense of _common_ is chosen!), one must be wary of demanding compositionality of fixed phrases. With a _ship of the desert_, is the ship powered by wind, steam, diesel, nuclear power?

Comment: @Edwin: Ah, I did not know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 4
>   a : widespread, general <common knowledge>
>   b : characterized by a lack of privilege or special status <common people>
>   c : just satisfying accustomed criteria : elementary <common decency>

It's covered by all of these. Common sense is supposed to be held by any reasonably mentally competent person; hence it is widespread, general, characterised by a lack of privilege or special status, and just satisfies the accustomed criteria of *sense* we expect everyone to reach.

Comment: I'm still not sold on 4b; I understand that common sense may well apply to all persons, but I wouldn't go so far as to say that it is *characterized* by that lack of privilege or special status.

Comment: Which? Either it applies to all people, or it's not characterised by a lack of privilege or special status. Those are two ways of saying the same thing.